# Entering APPID but APPID is not available in SP list Data connection display message

Tags: list, infopath, infopath-2013

In Infopath 2013, I have data connection (pulling data from SP list ) based on `ApplicationID` field and it happened but somehow, `ApplicationID` is not available.

Then how can I set message using rule?

Comment: What is application ID? How are you entering this in Infopath form and fetching the data from SharePoint List? Can you please add screenshot or something to understand your question?

Comment: @GaneshSanap i have one Drop-Down Control which i have saved all the APP ID under Drop-Down Properties. and also i have SP list which saved all the data. when selecting APP ID from Drop Down it will fetch data from that SP list data connection n display in Multiline text box. but my question is if select APP ID which data is not available in that list so that time it should be though message in Multiline Textbox